# onBackPressed() popBackStack issues

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have seen many of the popbackstack issues on SO and based on my code it looks like what I am trying to do should work.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new MainFragment());
        ft.addToBackStack("Attend"); //here is the add to backstack
        ft.commit();

    }
```

This shows my main fragment inside my blank layout.

Later I have a onOptionsItemSelected which kicks off a new fragment.

```
FragmentManager fm1 = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft1 = fm1.beginTransaction();
                ft1.replace(R.id.content_frame, new ServiceFragment());
                ft1.addToBackStack("ServiceTimes");
                ft1.commit();
                return true;
```

This fragment shows up. Here is where the problem starts. I press the back button expecting to go back to main fragment.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    if(fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"popstack",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        fm.popBackStackImmediate("Attend", fm.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Super",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

I added a Toast popup to show me what was happening and when the back button is pressed I get a blank white screen with "popstack" Toast message (Telling me the "if" statement is correct". When I hit it again I get "super" (again it is what I expect).

I don't understand why my code wont go back to the main fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something key to remember is that the back stack contains *transactions* and not Fragments.

Because you are using the `POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE` flag, the transaction with name `"Attend"` is also being popped (i.e. undone) when you hit the back button. Because this transaction added your first fragment programmatically, you are returned to the initial state of the Activity (no Fragments in the container with id `content_frame`).

The appropriate resolution depends on exactly what you are trying to achieve (how many Fragments may be added, do you always want to return to the first Fragment on back press, etc.) You may want to consider not adding the initial transaction to the back stack. Or you could add it, but not use the inclusive flag, and only use your custom onBackPressed logic if the back stack entry count is > 1.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didnt realize POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE did this. I changed to fm.popBackStackImmediate();